# Hibernate: Merge BLOB - workaround

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I read that Hibernate doesn't allow Merge function on blob attributes.

May I know is there a work around beside using .save ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using 3.x branch because in version 4.x this problem has been resolved.
You have to replace blob manually after merge, than save

```
Object merged = session.merge(original);
merged.setBlob(session.getLobHelper().createBlob(<use new data>));
session.save(merged);
```